Power Automate - look behind item in list for first occurence of phrase
I'm parsing text in Amazon PDF files to eventually put the information in a spreadsheet. Items in that document are stored in the list Items and their positions in list ItemPositions. Amazon item orders are grouped by their shipped date. I want to find the first occurrence of the phrase "Shipped On" and retrieve the rest of that line.
Screenshot of an Amazon order with three items and a Shipped On date at the top

I'm using a for each loop block to iterate through each item's position. I'm able to find the first occurrence of "Shipped On" after the position of the item, but I need the one before it.
Screenshot of the Parse block

